# Delphi - Change taskbar icon

Tags: delphi, dll, icons

I have main .exe app and .dll with form. From .exe I can create and show form from the .dll, but it has no taskbar icon (and the small one at the top left). I want to load this icon from another DLL. How can I do it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the things that you need to do. I've not included much detail because your question has little detail and there's no way for me to know exactly how you would fit all this into your program. The point is to make it clear at a high level what you need to do.

**Load the DLL containing the resource**

Do this using `LoadLibrary` or `LoadLibraryEx`. Use the former if you need to call code in the DLL. Otherwise use the latter passing `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE`. Both of these functions yield a module handle, `HMODULE`.

**Load the icon from the DLL**

Pass the `HMODULE` to `LoadIcon` or `LoadImage` to load the icon from a resource. These will yield an `HICON`. Assign that to the `Handle` property of an instance of `TIcon`.

**Assign the icon to the form**

Assign the icon object that you obtained in the previous step to the `Icon` property of your form.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much. I tried something like Form.Icon.Assign(Icon);, but it created AV error message. Here is working code:

```
procedure TformOptions.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  lib: THandle;
  icon: TIcon;
begin
  icon := TIcon.Create;
  lib := LoadLibrary('res.dll');
  if lib > 0 then icon.Handle := LoadIcon(lib, 'ICON2');
  if icon.Handle > 0 then Application.Icon.Assign(icon);
  icon.Free;
  FreeLibrary(lib);
end;
```

Comment: The AV will be because of an error in your code. Likely Form not valid. Test not equal to zero rather than greater than. Use LoadLibraryEx to avoid executing code in the dll. Use try finally. Simple assignment to Icon is more idiomatic than Assign.