# How to use the application icon for forms loaded from Delphi DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, dialog, icons

I have multiple Windows host applications and a DLL that are all created with Delphi. The DLL contains some (modal) dialog forms that are displayed on demand. I already pass the `Forms.Application.Handle` from the currently running host application to the DLL to get the right windows ownership. Unfortunately the dialog created from DLL still shows a generic icon instead of using the main application icon like done for dialogs that are created directly in the host application.

How can I get `tForm` based dialogs opened from DLLs to use the current application icon from the host executable instead of a generic Windows icon?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi - Change taskbar icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350774/delphi-change-taskbar-icon)

Comment: Are you talking about the window icon in the top-left, or the taskbar icon, or both?

Comment: @JerryDodge: I'm talking about the window top-left icon. There is no taskbar icon after I set `Forms.Application.Handle` in the DLL.

Comment: @SilverWarior: Your linked question explains how to load an icon from a DLL. In my case I want to use the application icon from the host EXE.

Comment: You could just manually set it directly on the form if you don't intend to ever dynamically change it in the future.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Unfortunately there are multiple different host applications with different icons so using a static icon in the DLL won't work. I have updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the host application icon can be handled to the DLL by passing the `Forms.Application.Icon.Handle` handle value to the library and assign it to the tApplication instance there.

Dummy library code:

```
procedure MyLib_SetAppIcon( Icon : hIcon ); stdcall;
begin
   if (Icon > 0) then
      Forms.Application.Icon.Handle := Icon;
end;
```

Dummy host code:

```
procedure MyLib_SetAppIcon( Icon : hIcon ); stdcall; external 'MyLib.dll';

// ...
MyLib_SetAppIcon(Forms.Application.Icon.Handle);
// ...
```